# iptables allow request started by server

Tags: linux, iptables

As you can image, we need iptables to block the ports we do not need to protect server.
But I need to request some third party resource, and I got confuse on how to do it.
Here are my iptables rules

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -p UDP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 110.75.147.65/32 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s localhost -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

And **110.75.147.65/32** is the one of third party servers' IP, I wonder if there are any way to allow all connection started by my server such as `curl https://www.google.com/`, otherwise I need to add all my third party servers' IP to the iptables rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```